# Поисковая функция на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for

всем привет! помогите, пожалуйста, написать функцию которая будет возвращать нужный `id` в зависимости от заданного значения `flights`
Есть такая структура:

```
res = {
    "variants": [
        {
            "id": "0001",
            "price": {
                "amount": "4113"
            },
            "count": 7,
            "coordinates": {
                "x": 10,
                "y": 50
            },
            "segments": [
                {
                    "flights": [
                        "MOW"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "subvariants": []
        },
        {
            "id": "0002",
            "price": {
                "amount": "6338"
            },
            "count": 4,
            "coordinates": {
                "x": 0,
                "y": 12
            },
            "segments": [
                {
                    "flights": [
                        "LED"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "subvariants": []
        }
    ]
}
```

и хочу сделать при вызове `main(res, "LED")` что бы возвращалось `0002`

Comment: Хочешь — сделай. В предыдущем вопросе тебе уже дали достаточно информации, чтобы решить эту простенькую задачу самостоятельно.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
res = '''{
    "variants": [
        {
            "id": "0001",
            "price": {
                "amount": "4113"
            },
            "count": 7,
            "coordinates": {
                "x": 10,
                "y": 50
            },
            "segments": [
                {
                    "flights": [
                        "MOW"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "subvariants": []
        },
        {
            "id": "0002",
            "price": {
                "amount": "6338"
            },
            "count": 4,
            "coordinates": {
                "x": 0,
                "y": 12
            },
            "segments": [
                {
                    "flights": [
                        "LED"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "subvariants": []
        }
    ]
}
'''

j=json.loads(res)
for el in j['variants']:
    if el['segments'][0]['flights'][0]=='LED':
        print(f'id {el["id"]}')
```

---

```
id 0002
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def main(res, air):
    for i in res['variants']:
        if any(air in k['flights'] for k in i['segments']):
            return i['id']
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]